# How to send multiple features in the SOE response for the multi point input locations?

Tags: arcgis-server

For multi point input locations, I need to send multiple features in the SOE response. How do we combine the multiple `byte[]`

```py
result = FindNearFeatures(layerID, location, distance.Value);
```